# Using if and not "if and only if" in definitions

Tags: definition

We often see the word "if" in connection with definitions e.g

y is a solution of $x^{'}=f(x,t)$ if $y^{'}=f(y,t)$ or

A metric space is complete if every cauchy sequence converges.

Why isnt it written if and only if in general in this context?

Comment: Normally "iff" means "if and only if" in mathematical texts.

Comment: It's conventional to use "if" instead of "if and only if" in definitions.  You are correct in that "if and only if" is intended, but this is generally understood.

Comment: "A if B" means $B \Rightarrow A$. "A iff B" means $B \iff A$.

Comment: Because it is a definition. A definition is assumed to be declaring two expressions to be the same thing.  The "if" in a definition is not mathematical but colloquial. We can replace it with "when" or "is defined to be" or even ":" if we want to.